# Using login info to scrape a website with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape articles off a news website, to which I have a subscription, using `lxml`.

I am logged into the website on every browser on my computer (not that this matters?), but whenever I try to get any text from specific articles, using the following:

> page = requests.get("http://www.SomeWebsite.com/blah/blah/blah.html")
>
> tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
>
> article = tree.xpath('//div/p/text()')

I get the following response:

> ['You have viewed your allowance of free articles. If you wish to view more, click the button below.']

Any ideas or suggestions on how to get around this?

Disclaimer:  I'm new to python and web scraping

**EDIT**:  Solution posted below using Selenium library

Comment: Selenium is a good library for dealing with buttons and interactive javascript--there are good Python bindings available as well.

Comment: Thanks for the recs, I will check these libraries

Comment: @duhaime, Selenium bindings worked like a charm.  I will post my solution

Comment: @mrp: glad to hear it! It's a phenomenal package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the website I was trying to scrape was rejecting all post requests I would send it (I tried Python, R, and PHP) and I found that I could only load the news articles with an actual browser.

Thanks to @duhaime, I used Selenium to accomplish this.  Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

# I used Firefox, but you could use Chrome or IE
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.SomeWebsite.com/login')
# I needed to stop the script here to actually login.
# I tried to use an existing profile w/ my username & password but the website
# rejected my profile info and locked me out of the account

browser.get('http://www.SomeWebsite.com/blah/blah/blah.html')

element = browser.find_element_by_id("TheElementYouNeed").text
# This downloads all the text from the article at this particle 'id' element
```

Docs for Selenium bindings:  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#introduction

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to **scrape** a website and display it in yours, possibly in a better way.

So I would recommend to use [KIMONO](https://www.kimonolabs.com/), Its an web scraping service, which will provide you with the api to get the data in a proper Model.

Check it out, IT should get your job done.

If not you can create your own **scraper** in PHP [(PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser)](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)  or Javascript, there are libraries in Javascript also.

Sorry no idea on Python, But using Kimono's api you can do it in python also.

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with PHP, I will try it out tonight/tomorrow and get back..